# Audience targetted link hidden from everyone

Tags: navigation, audience-targeting

I have 4 manually created links across my top link bar. I want to use Audience Targetting to allow certain people to see it and to hide it from everyone else (I know audience targetting is not security, I have sorted permissions also). 
However, with my SharePoint group assigned as the target audience it now hides the link from EVERYONE, whether they're a member of the group or not.

Comment: Is User profile serivces configured on the servere?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to hide/show links in top navigation bar ?
If so, you can assign group level permissions to page which you want to hide .
i.e.

1. click edit page in site action menu
2. select page tab in command bar and click on Page permissions from ribbon
3. it will redirect you to permissions page and click on stop inheriting permissions and select the group for which you dont want to display that page and click on remove user permissions.

So that that page will not be displayed to particular selected group users.